# Cant use httpApi while deploying lambda functions to LocalStack using serverless

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, localstack

I am fairly new to serverless overall, and trying to set up LocalStack on my machine.
I have successfully deployed a test lambda function to LocalStack, but currently facing a problem regarding API Gateway.

While deploying with the configuration below, everything works correcty, and i am able to access the lambda function correctly using http, and the resulting endpoint is printed at the end of the deployment as usual:

```
service: localtest

frameworkVersion: ">=1.74.1"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: local

plugins:
  - serverless-localstack

custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
      - local
    host: http://localhost  
    autostart: true 
    endpoints:
      S3: http://localhost:4566
      DynamoDB: http://localhost:4566
      CloudFormation: http://localhost:4566
      Elasticsearch: http://localhost:4566
      ES: http://localhost:4566
      SNS: http://localhost:4566
      SQS: http://localhost:4566
      Lambda: http://localhost:4566
      Kinesis: http://localhost:4566
    lambda:
      mountCode: True
    docker:
      sudo: False

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: /
```

The resulting  output from `serverless deploy`:

```
Service Information
service: localtest
stage: local
region: us-east-1
stack: localtest-local
resources: 10
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  http://localhost:4567/restapis/720w6afoyh/local/_user_request_
functions:
  hello: localtest-local-hello
layers:
  None
```

However, when trying to use the httpApi implementation in the events

```
 - httpApi:
          method: get
          path: /
```

i get several errors from localstack, and the function seems to by deployed but does not output a path.

the error log from LocalStack:

```
2020-07-09T11:39:50:WARNING:moto: No Moto CloudFormation support for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
2020-07-09T11:39:50:WARNING:moto: No Moto CloudFormation support for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
2020-07-09T11:39:50:WARNING:moto: No Moto CloudFormation support for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
2020-07-09T11:39:50:WARNING:moto: No Moto CloudFormation support for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
2020-07-09T11:39:50:WARNING:moto: No Moto CloudFormation support for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
2020-07-09T11:39:55:WARNING:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Unable to resolve "Ref" attribute for: {'Ref': 'HelloLambdaVersionFjNrIW0CS0DGT44Agi2AjgeDtzxVf8vf0JBR6XRariM'} - HelloLambdaVersionFjNrIW0CS0DGT44Agi2AjgeDtzxVf8vf0JBR6XRariM - <class 'moto.awslambda.models.LambdaVersion'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. This is apparently only supported in the **pro** version of localstack, not the free one.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) note that HTTP APIs use the -v2 version of API Gateway, and this is only supported, according to the [localstack repo](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), in the pro version.